# Create floating view with custom outline like in Notability

Tags: swiftui

How to create such a view floating view with a custom boarder as shown in the picture? And such that it disappears as soon as the user clicks outside of the view.
[image: to]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would do that with a `Popover` like this:

```
@State var isPresented = false
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.isPresented = true
    }) {
        Text("Press me")
    }.popover(isPresented: $isPresented, arrowEdge: .top) {
        Text("Pop!") // You can put you own custom view here for the popover
    }
}
```

Although it works as intended on the iPad (and I believe tvOS too, but I haven't tested it), it does not work properly with the current version of SwiftUI (as of 10/12/2019) on iPhones. Currently, the above code will just result in a somewhat glitchy modal on an iPhone, which I don't think is the intended function of it on iPhones. Apple's documentation for popover isn't very helpful right now, but [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/angulargradient/3353202-popover) it is anyway.

[image: iPad and iPhone popover example/comparison]

Answer (score 0):

For you information .popover is unabailable in tvOS.